# Count the number of files under a directory (including files under subdirectories)

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to find the total number of files under a directory which is present on my company's shared drive. But I do not have the permission to access some of the folders (Strictly restricted) inside several subdirectories. I am using Windows PowerShell but getting many errors saying, **PERMISSION DENIED** along with the path of the folder which it inaccessible. Below is the command I used,

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

My question is, Is there a way to find the total number of files in all the directories and subdirectories, **ignoring those restricted files which are causing the errors?**

Answer (score 1):

just do it

```
  (gci -Path C:\temp -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count
```

Comment: Did not get the count as output, instead it is listing the files in couple of directories, that's it.

Comment: If yours dirs are not enable you cant count, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 3.0 and higher:

```
(Get-Childitem -Recurse -path x:\whatever -erroraction SilentlyContinue | where {-not ($_.PSIsContainer)}).count
```

You might still see errors, but you'll get an answer

Comment: I don't think it is counting all the files in accessible folders. It is showing me a very small count

Comment: This is more PS2 than PS3 ? But the result is accurate.

Comment: PS2 does not support auto enrollment, what we are using here.

Comment: Please verify that you dont have more files there

Answer (score 0):

Let me try:

```
Get-Childitem "C:\Users" -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Measure-Object |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```